# Website backgrounds

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add a background image to my homepage and make the image full screen. The code I've used cuts the image off at the bottom and I have no idea why.

```
CSS Code used:
body {
        background-image: url(../images/background.png);
        background-size:100% auto;
        margin-bottom:;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    HTML Code:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My Subconscious</title>
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="maincontainer">

    <div id"header">
        <p>What is going on?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    <a href="Index.html">Welcome</a>
    <a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="1.html">1</a> 
    <a href="2.html">2</a>
    <a href="3.html">3</a> 
    <a href="contactMe">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***Cuts image at bottom*** - can you clarify?

Comment: I'd say your image is higher than it's large, right? If so you need to set 100% on the height.

Comment: you can use the `background-size: cover;` so that the background will be spread to the entire screen.

Comment: @rockStar I used that css and it seems the same as what I had already put. The image is still getting cut off :S

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have this one `margin-bottom:;`. This will faultly render your `CSS`. Remove that line and try it again with `background-size: 100%;` (if that won't work, you can use `background-size: cover;`.

While your busy, try this too:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.png) no-repeat;
```

In this case, you don't have to use `background-repeat`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. Now the background has gone, when I  change the no-repeat option.

Comment: No the background is still getting cut off at the bottom. I don't know if it is a problem with the html div structure or if something else on the css is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
.full-page-bg
{
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/MRnG4/)

good luck!

Comment: How do you link in the code? Is it by using a class? Thanks

Comment: @Jamax91x its not necessary to use a class... just cut/paste css and use it where you want and don't forget to change the url in background property. It should be working fine now.